# Write text file into a zip without temp files

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

In the code below, I need to wright `package.inf` directly into the zip file created at the bottom of the script.

```
import os
import zipfile

print("Note: All theme files need to be inside of the 'theme_files' folder.")
themeName = input("\nTheme name: ")
themeAuthor = input("\nTheme author: ")
themeDescription = input("\nTheme description: ")
themeContact = input("\nAuthor contact: ")
otherInfo = input("\nAdd custom information? y/n: ")
if otherInfo == "y":
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    print("\nEnter extra theme package information below.\n--------------------\n")
    themeInfo = input()

pakName = themeName.replace(" ", "_").lower()

pakInf = open("package.inf", "w")
pakInf.write("Theme name: "+ themeName +"\n"+"Theme author: "+ themeAuthor +"\n"+"Theme description: "+ themeDescription +"\n"+"Author contact: "+ themeContact)
if otherInfo == "y":
    pakInf.write("\n"+ themeInfo)

pakInf.close()

themePak = zipfile.ZipFile(pakName +".tpk", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("theme_files"):
    themePak.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        themePak.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

themePak.close()
```

Write `pakInf` into `themePak` without creating any temporary files.

Comment: You could use `StringIO` and `BytesIO` from the `io` module.

Comment: @Squall Could I please have that in answer format with an example to get me started? I have never done anything like that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `io.StringIO` to create a file-like object in memory:

```
import io
import os
import zipfile

print("Note: All theme files need to be inside of the 'theme_files' folder.")
themeName = input("\nTheme name: ")
themeAuthor = input("\nTheme author: ")
themeDescription = input("\nTheme description: ")
themeContact = input("\nAuthor contact: ")
otherInfo = input("\nAdd custom information? y/n: ")
if otherInfo == "y":
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    print("\nEnter extra theme package information below.\n--------------------\n")
    themeInfo = input()

pakName = themeName.replace(" ", "_").lower()

pakInf = io.StringIO()
pakInf.write("Theme name: "+ themeName +"\n"+"Theme author: "+ themeAuthor +"\n"+"Theme description: "+ themeDescription +"\n"+"Author contact: "+ themeContact)
if otherInfo == "y":
    pakInf.write("\n"+ themeInfo)

themePak = zipfile.ZipFile(pakName +".tpk", "w")
themePak.writestr("package.inf", pakInf.getvalue())
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("theme_files"):
    themePak.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        themePak.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

themePak.close()
```